# Comparing an image with different anti-aliasing

Tags: image-processing, blur

I have two files of the exact same image, but each has a slightly different amount of anti-aliasing.  Say I want to compare these two images to see if they are exactly the same image.  I cannot simply do a pixel-by-pixel comparison because they may not match in every pixel.  What filter should I apply to each image such that any differences introduced by anti aliasing is eliminated (or significantly reduced)? Should I apply some type of blur to both images?